# give several parameters to a function with 1 variable/object

Tags: javascript

as an example i take jQuery animate function:
normal it works like this:

```
$("#div1").animate({
                width: '300px',
            }, 1000, function() {
                console.log("animate 1 done");
            });
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
animateConfig = [{
                width: '300px',

            }, 1000, function() {
                console.log("animate1 done");
            }];

startAnimate($("#div1"), animateConfig);

function startAnimate(obj, animateConfig) {
    console.log(animateConfig);
    obj.animate(animateConfig);

}
```

also a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hVXKM/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
obj.animate.apply(obj, animateConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.animate()` method lets you pass an object as a second parameter. That way you can do this:

Docs: [.animate( properties, options )](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

```
animateConfig = {
    props: { width: '300px' },
    options: {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
           console.log("animate1 done");
        }
    }
}
```

So then you can just do this:

```
function startAnimate(obj, config) {
    obj.animate(config.props, config.options);
}

startAnimate(obj, animateConfig);
```